# Unable to debug steps file afterupgrading from Specflow 2 to 3.5.5

Tags: debugging, nunit, specflow

SpecFlow Version:
3.5.5

Test Runer
NUNit

Version 3.12.0

Visual Studio version
2019

.Net
.Net 4.7.2

Specflow ext:
2019.0.68.11251

Test Execution Method:
Resharper

I am able to hit break points in the feature file but not able to hit break points in steps file.

Also I have noticed under my specs in test explorer I now have Root Namespace followed by _Specs_NUnitAssemblyHooks

Comment: Try deleting the .vs folder inside your Visual Studio solution. It is a hidden folder that contains a bunch of temp files.